# Why does my Acer aspire make a clicking sound when switched on?

Tags: laptop

I get a continuous clicking sound from my Acer Aspire One when I turn it on, along with a blank black screen. Can anyone help please.

Comment: This sounds like a failed hard drive, but you've given us very little information. Have you tried booting to a CD (Windows or Ubuntu CD) or running any diagnostics?

Answer (score 2):

> continuous clicking sound

Compare to the sound you get to hear at 2:24 in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5CAn22TiVV0

If that is what you hear, then you have a broken hard drive.

The guy in the video opens the drive and shows that **he** can get it running again. But knowing all the facts there is NO WAY to do that in a normal home or office AND HAVE IT OPERATE RELIABLY for **elongated time** from that point. A load of comments on the video indicates otherwise, and may be that they were lucky: The health status of devices like this IS very dependent on how you treat them.
I'd say the speaker is sitting in a controlled environment e.g. a lower class of ["clean room"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_room).

Answer (score -1):

It is a beep sound that you are getting in when you are starting your laptop, there are few possible reasons which leads to this type of sounds.

> 1.Bad Ram.
>
> 2.Loos connection with memory sticks.

try removing and re installing the ram sticks it may solve your problem.

see below taken form the following source:
http://en.kioskea.net/faq/344-how-to-recognize-beep-errors

> **How to recognize the beep errors:**
>
> Very short beep
>    :This problem is linked to your motherboard. It can also mean that you are facing a problem with your system memory (BIOS AWARD)
>
> Short beep
>    :No problem.
>
> Long beep followed by three sequential short beeps.
>    :This issue is linked to your graphics card configurations.
>
> Short beep followed by three sequential long beeps
>    :You are facing a system memory problem.
>
> Beep, pause, beep, pause, two sequential beeps
>    :This error is linked to your CPU.
>
> Three beeps, pause, three beeps, pause, four beeps
>    :You have an issue with the video memory.
>
> One long beep and nine short
>    :Problem with the ROM (Bios AWARD).
>
> Three beeps, pause, four beeps, pause, beep
>    :This is linked to an error with your graphics card.
>
> Four beeps, pause, three beeps, pause, beep
>    :You have a system memory problem.
>
> Five short beeps
>    :You are facing a problem with your CPU.
>
> Long constant beeps
>    :It's a system memory problem.
>
> **Tips**
>
> If your PC beeps after the OS has been launched, it may be due to the fact that your CPU is overheating and that could be a serious matter.

Comment: They said they get a clicking sound, not beeping.

Comment: @CharlieRB He is telling continuous clicking sound with blank black screen If the sound come from hard disk then blank black screen will not come it will say something regarding the disk error. If any other error or sound is coming except the above the blank black screen will not come it will say something please think before downvoting.

Comment: You logic is flawed. The beeping you refer to in your answer is for BIOS beep codes. The OP has indicated clicking and a blank screen, not beeping when powered on. So, to assume beep codes will provide the answer is a large leaping conclusion. A PC can post without error and not start Windows because of a failed hard drive.

Comment: That makes no sense at all. You chose to give your answer based on your belief the OP asked the wrong question? You may want to consider using the comment section under the question to get clarification from the OP before making those conclusions. The comment section is specifically for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for correcting but This is not My belief If you read the question clearly you will also conclude that what he is asking as I told you in my previous comments.

Answer (score -2):

My cousins gave me a completely dead computer. I did some hardware testing turns out the charger port on the computer was broken I replaced with a 16v power supply but the computer is rated to have 19v      That leads me to conclude that either you bought the wrong charger, a rip-off one, or you have to many devices on a circuit ie too many things on a power strip     If you have the same problem as me hold the power button and the clicking should speed up

Comment: Failing power supplies don't typically make clicking noises. Possibly popping noises, but not clicking.