# RAM buffer access makes beep/screech

Tags: linux, memory, hardware-failure, buffer

When I execute `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1G count=1`, I hear a curious, very soft- screeching sound (think HD spinup but shorter, softer, and higher pitched) from where I know my RAM is located (Dell Inspiron 17R laptop). Presumably, this is because of buffering 1G of zeroes in RAM before discarding them.

**Why does my system do this, and is something wrong?** For the record, my RAM has in the past also occasionally done this, but I can repeat it pretty well now. If you want system information, please also tell me how to access it.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/792162/why-does-my-acer-aspire-make-a-clicking-sound-when-switched-on/792179#792179

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt its your ram, its probably another component that is powering the ram that is screeching, like a powerphase cap or something.

But by the look if the service Manuel the hard drive is near the ram so could be that per ali783's comment.  But  as the command you have run only uses memory I don't know think it would be.

If this problem has only happened under load I wouldn't worry to much, otherwise it could be the sign of a failing component on the board